# Whittaker and Watson book prerequisites

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, special-functions

I am thinking of reading the landmark book by Whittaker and Watson on modern analysis. However, I couldn't find enough information about what it assumes the reader to know in maths (i.e. reader's background). Could any one help?  Also, do you know of any similar/equivalent books that may act as more modern replacements? Books that are closer to applied than pure maths are the flavour sought.

Thanks.

Comment: If you start at the beginning, and you know Calculus, then the book is fairly self-contained. Modern Analysis at that time (early 20th century) involved much more about special functions of Math Physics and explicitly solving differential equations of Math-Physics. Are you looking for more about explicit solutions of ODEs and PDEs, or you are you looking for more about how Analysis looks now?

Comment: @TrialAndError Thanks for this. I am interested in learning a solid and well-rounded foundation in Analysis before I proceed to Mathematical Physics texts (e.g. Jeffreys and Jeffreys, Morse and Feshbach, or others). My impression is that such step is important. My original background is PhD in electromagnetic engineering. My understanding was this is a classic book that remains largely the standard text in practical analysis. Is this correct? I'd appreciate any suggestions or comparisons or roadmaps that would lead to strong 'backbone' in Math Physics, including PDE/ODE methods and more.

Comment: @TrialAndError ... also, out of curiosity, why did you highlight their use of explicit solutions of PDEs/ODEs? Was this meant to contrast it with implicit solutions, or did you mean that there are other treatment methods now that are not specifically for Math Physics? Do you imply any pros or cons in their treatment compared to more modern ones? Please advise.

Comment: Modern treatments in Mathematics tend to focus on existence and uniqueness, and don't delve so much into the gory details of explicit solutions. For Physics and Engineering I really need to see explicit solutions. For a difficult and specific example, one explicit solution is worth a thousand theorems. :)

Comment: @TrialAndError  So, what texts would you recommend for such explicit treatment of realistic (difficult) problems in engineering and physics? Would Whittaker and Watson be a good candidate or do you recommend others?

Comment: Based on  wanting "explicit treatment of realistic (difficult) problems in engineering and physics," the books you mentioned would be good choices. However I don't believe Whittaker and Watson have much about Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: As a reference for explicit solutions, check out the Bateman Manuscript Project. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman_Manuscript_Project

Comment: @T Many thanks for your great help.

Comment: @Trial Hi again. Just another quick point on Whittaker and Watson. In its second half, it starts treating special functions, one per chapter. Say I wanted to delve into  Bessel's functions without doing the rest of the book, would that be possible, or are the chapters inter-dependent and I need to read other chapters first? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think most of the chapters on special functions are independent, but all of them depend on the analysis chapters. So I suspect you'll have no problem starting with the Bessel functions.

Comment: @Disi Hi again. Do you have any advice regarding Morse & Feshbach versus Jeffreys & Jeffreys books? Which one more useful for self-study to master and be skilled in methods for mathematical physics? Or which one to start with if time is limited? Any advice is appreciated.